# Black area issue in landscape mode on left side of screen Ios 8.1 cocos2dx

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, ios8.1

Please check this image below taken from the simulator(iphone 6 ios 8.1 cocos2dx v3.2)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sht87og5ga4t427/offsetleft.png?dl=0

There is a black area on the left side but when i run the app in ios 7.1 simulator, there is no black area. I also noticed when i switch the app orientation to potrait then there is no black area in ios 8.1 simulator.

And below is the image taken from ios 8.1 simulator as a screen shot and strange thing is that it has no black area as shown in the above image. I do not have real iphone 6 or plus. Its just my guess that as the below screenshot is showing no black area so is it how the app will look like on a real device? Is that black area is just a simulator issue? Please confirm if anyone faced this issue.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybc8xvl7ten4rmt/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Dec%2024%2C%202014%2C%207.55.10%20AM.png?dl=0

Design Resolution in the AppDelegate

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
if(!glview) {
    glview = GLView::create("My Game");
    director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}

Size designSize = Size(960, 640);
Size frameSize = glview->getFrameSize();
glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width, designSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::EXACT_FIT);

std::vector<std::string> searchPaths;
searchPaths.push_back("fonts");
FileUtils::getInstance()->setSearchPaths(searchPaths);

// turn on display FPS
director->setDisplayStats(true);

// set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
director->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);
```

Comment: please import the picture instead of giving link

Comment: I can`t because of lesser reputation.

Comment: Have you called the method `setDesignResolutionSize` in your AppDelegate.cpp file?

Comment: @owen please check above the design resolution and policy i am using.

Comment: what is the size of your resource ??  & have you uploaded launch images for iphone 6 & 6++ ?!!